# How to change "Keyboard Input Method System" to "None" in Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: keyboard, ibus

Every time I install the default version of Ubuntu 14.04 (with Unity), I go to "Language Support" and change the option "Keyboard Input Method System" to "None", because I need it that way.

Today, I installed Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 and I can't find this "Keyboard Input Method System" option anywhere. Please, how do I change this when using Gnome Shell?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `im-config` to change this. My system wil laccept `ibus` or `xim`. The latter reports as "none" in the GUI.

```
im-config -n ibus
im-config -n xim
```

Answer (score 2):

In Terminal:

```
$ gnome-language-selector
```

Open the Language tab, and there you can choose IBus or None.